# Example of non-zero object of an abelian category that is both injective and projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

In the category of R-modules an object that is both injective and projective is [necessarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585495/a-problem-about-an-r-module-that-is-both-injective-and-projective) the zero module.

Are there any abelian categories with examples non-zero objects that are both injective and projective?

Comment: Well that's not true if $R$ is a field for starters, or not a domain in general : if $k$ is a field and $G$ a finite group, then $k[G]$-injective and $k[G]$-projective mean the same thing

Comment: In a semisimple category all sequences split so all objects are injective and projective.

Comment: semisimple rings are characterized by having all modules projective and injective.  Quasi-frobenius rings are characterized by the fact their injective modules are precisely their projective modules. So the proposition you’re citing isn’t true in general. Notice your link is talking about *nonfield domains*.