# Let $D$ be an integral domain which is not field and $Q=\text{Frac}(D)$. Then $Q$ has not a projective cover as $D$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Let $D$ be an integral domain which is not a field and $Q=\text{Frac}(D)$ the field of fractions of $D$. Then $Q$ as a $D$-module has not a projective cover.

By **Corollary 5.35** of Rotman's *Homological Algebra* we got that : *If $D$ is an integral domain and $Q=\text{Frac}(D)$, then $Q$ is a flat $D$-module*.

So we got it, $Q$ is a flat $D$-module, now my idea is to use **Bass Theorem** to kill this one, this theorem states (among other things) that $M_{R}$ has projective cover ($M_{R}$ is perfect) iff every $M_{R}$ flat module is projective.

So I reduced (or complicated :S) the problem to prove that the flat module $Q_{D}$ is not projective, which is the part I cannot prove. I tried to study the proof of $\mathbb{Q}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a flat module that is not projective but they use the fact $\mathbb{Q}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is finitely generated and that $\mathbb{Z}$ is DIP but in my case I dont know if $Q_{D}$ is finitely generated, also $D$ is not be DIP. Any help in order to prove this problem in the direction I propose or any other will be apreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a hint, note that $Q=\text{Frac}(D)$ is also injective as an $R$-module. Therefore to show that it is not projective you can show that there are no non-zero projective-injective modules over $D$.

There is also a solution to this problem on this site, which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585495/a-problem-about-an-r-module-that-is-both-injective-and-projective). This is actually exercise 3.18 in Rotman's Intro to Homological Algebra, 2nd edition, so you might want to try and prove it using his hints.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zeek!  Already tried the last problem I asked about semi-perfect cover with the definition of indecomposable in Kasch book that Rickard mentioned in the comments. Let me write that on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

As a non zero projective module has maximal submodules, if K had a projective cover, then K would have a maximal submodule (The maximal submodules of a projective cover of K are in bijective correspondence with the maximal submodules of K). Then it would be a divisible simple module, which can not exist.

Comment: Thanks! But I got confused following you. Lets say $K=Frac(D)$ and suppose that $K$ has a proyective cover  and also supposing $K$ is projective :/ ?  Lets say $P$ then $P$ have a maximal submodule which is in correpondence with  a maximal submodule of $K$. I know already that $K$ is divisible but why it would also be simple? @Hugo