# A module over PID which is not direct sum of cyclic mdules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

I am trying to solve the following qualifying exam problem: “Give an example of a module over a PID that is not isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic modules. Justify your example”. (Carnegie Mellon, 2022 Algebra Qual Q1)

**My attempt:** By the *Structure Theorem of Finitely Generated Modules over PIDs*, if $M$ is a finitely generated module over a PID $R$, then $$M \cong R^n \oplus R/p_1^{n_1} \oplus \dotsb \oplus R / p_k^{n_k} $$ where $n_1, \dotsc, n_k \ge 0$ and $p_1, \dotsc, p_k$ are primes in $R$. Thus, we are looking for a module $M$ over a PID $R$, which is not finitely generated.  Can I just pick any module which is not finitely generated? Or should I be more careful about the choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if $M$ is not finitely generated you still need to find such an $M$ for which you can prove that it's not a direct sum of cyclic modules, since some infinitely generated modules *are* (infinite) such direct sums.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you for your answer. Can give elaborate more on how to search for such a module $M$?

Comment: Well, what's the simplest example of a PID you know? Can you name some interesting infinitely generated modules over it?

Comment: $Z$ is the simplest PID I guess and any finitely generated abelian group is a fg module over $Z$.

Comment: *Very* related: [How can we show that $\mathbb Q$ is not a free $\mathbb Z$-module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129337/how-can-we-show-that-mathbb-q-is-not-a-free-mathbb-z-module)

Answer (score 5):

Try $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, which is a PID. Note that any two cyclic submodules of $\mathbb{Q}$ intersects nontrivially.

Comment: In my mind this is more of a comment than an answer - proving that $\mathbb Q$ is not a direct sum of cyclic modules (i.e. cyclic Abelian groups) is not hard, but the OP may not be able to see it immediately. Luckily, there is a proof [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129337/how-can-we-show-that-mathbb-q-is-not-a-free-mathbb-z-module).

Answer (score 4):

Actually if $R$ is any PID that is not a field, then its fraction field $F(R)$ is an example. If $F(R)$ is a direct sum of cyclic $R$-modules, since it's torsion-free, it must be free, i.e. $F(R)\simeq \oplus_{i\in I}R$ where $I\not=\emptyset$. Then we pick a nonzero noninvertible element $r\in R$, and we have $F(R)\otimes R/(r)=\{0\}$ while $(\oplus_{i\in I}R)\otimes R/(r)\simeq\oplus_{i\in I}R/(r)\not=\{0\}$.

From another point of view, $F(R)$ is injective, and hence [cannot be projective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585495/a-problem-about-an-r-module-that-is-both-injective-and-projective) or free.

Another famous result is that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb Z$ is not a free $\mathbb Z$-module, but [this is much harder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module).